# How to draw shapes with outline and fill with nothing in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How to draw shapes like rectangle, circle with only outline (fill with **transparent color** inside) in AS3 like this
[rectangle](http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=10501265) and [circle](http://ak2.polyvoreimg.com/cgi/img-thing/size/l/tid/6981592.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `graphics.lineStyle` with `graphics.drawRect` or `graphics.drawCircle`.

```
// this means you want to draw a line on the outer edge
// 1 is thickness, and you got more options like color, etc.
graphics.lineStyle(1);
// draw rect
graphics.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
// draw circle
graphics.drawCircle(x, y, radius);
```

Thanks to @BotMaster for pointing out you don't need begin/end fill.

Comment: if there' no need for inside color then there's no need for beginFill at all.

Comment: Haha nice one, my fault! :) Edited. Thanks for pointing it out ;)